# Batch files for Adding random numbers (3 digits) in front of files and for removing the numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, command-line, batch-rename

I'm interested in 2 batch files: one that generates random numbers (3 digits) and puts them in front of every MP3 file in a folder, and the other batch for removing these random numbers.

My attempt at the first batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for %%i in (*.mp3) do ( ren "%%i" "!RANDOM!%%i" ) 
endlocal
```

The problem: the numbers are up to 5 digits.

My attempt at the second batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
for %%i in (*.mp3) do (set name=%%i && ren "!name!" "!name:~3!") 
endlocal
```

The problem: it removes 6 characters from the first file.

Comment: Cool. Where's your attempt at the code?

Comment: @thomas **Do not post code in comments**. What I see is that you are putting `setlocal` and `for` command together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could be interested in these two Batch files that I wrote some time ago:

**Scramble songs.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Scramble *.mp3 files inserting a random number in their names
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Create a list of numbers in natural order for all files
rem with four digits each and a separation space
cd "%~DP0\My Music in 4GB"
set i=10000
set "list="
for %%a in (*.mp3) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "list=!list!!i:~-4! "
)
set /A i-=10000

rem Extract random elements from the list of numbers
rem and use they in the new name of the files
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp3') do (
   echo !i!-  "%%a"
   set /A "randElem=!random! %% i * 5, i-=1"
   for %%r in (!randElem!) do for /F %%s in ("!list:~%%r,4!") do (
      setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
      ren "%%a" "%%s- %%a"
      endlocal
      set "list=!list:%%s =!"
   )
)

pause
```

**Unscramble songs.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Unscramble the *.mp3 files removing the random number from their names
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

cd "%~DP0\My Music in 4GB"
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp3') do (
   echo %%a  "%%b"
   ren "%%a %%b" "%%b"
)

pause
```

The first Batch file insert a four-digits number before each song because my 4GB card can accept more than 1000 songs, but I am pretty sure you may modify this code in order to reduce the number to 3 digits...

Comment: Thanks for the codes! However, for usage with software, the file names should be without spaces. (At least for some software.) I didn't have much success to adjust the second code for it.

Comment: **1.** In first code eliminate the space between the dash and the filename in `ren "%%a" "%%s- %%a"` command. **2.** In second code add `delims=-` after `tokens=1*` and change the space by a dash in `ren "%%a %%b" "%%b"` command. May I ask you to upvote and select this answer?

Comment: Done. However, since I have less than 15 reputation, my upvote doesn't change the score.

Answer (score 0):

- To get a random number with 3 places you can do a modulus division by
  1000
- to get leading zeroes for numbers below 100 you can add 1000 and only
  use the last 3 places of the number.
- to ease the splitting of the number I'd use a delimiter like `_`

---

```
 @Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "Delims=_"
 for %%i in (*.mp3) do (
     Set /A RndNum=1000+!Random! %% 1000
     Echo Ren "%%i" "!RndNum:~-3!%Delims%%%i" 
 )
 Pause
```

For testing purposes the ren command is prepended with an echo,
remove it when the output is OK.

```
@Echo off
Set "Delims=_"
For /F "tokens=1,* Delims=%Delims%" %%A in (
    'Dir /B "???%Delims%*.mp3" '
) do Echo ren "%%A%Delims%%%B" "%%B"
Pause
```