# How to randomize file order on folders with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

am trying to get a batch file to help me randomize files.
Files are videos/music/text/doc

To be more specific, lets say am having the following files on a folder named like this:

```
3020_1
3020_2
3020_3
3020_4
3020_5
6031_1
6032_2
5013_1
6060_1
```

Windows will sort them as above, and i would like to get a folder with the above files to appear randomly.

Can you guys help me out :)

Comment: I suggest you to read  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135663/batch-files-for-adding-random-numbers-3-digits-in-front-of-files-and-for-remov/45147449#45147449)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are aware of the fact that the order of appearance of files in a Windows folder depends on the `sort` option you have chosen. Assuming you still want to do this in a given sorted view and you are OK renaming files, you can try the `ren` command to do this. Find more details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx)

```
ren 3020_1 3020_2
```

Since you want this to be random, you will have to add a bit of logic to get a random file name.

`%RANDOM%` will give you a random number every time you execute it. More information on that is available [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html)

Hope this gets you move further

Comment: In batch the natural sort order depends on the drive type. NTFS returns the files alpha sorted.